Volume of figure locked of the surfaces $z^2 = x y$ and $\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{3}\right)^4 = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{6}}$, where $x,y,z \geq 0$
I need to find the volume of the figure locked of the surfaces  $z^2 = x  y$ and $\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{3}\right)^4 = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{6}}$, where $x,y,z \geq 0$
I know I need to find the polar coordinates and constraints.
I need to do something like $x = r\cos(\phi)$ and $y = r\sin(\phi)$.
Then, I must solve a double integral (which I can't create).
Any help?

The top surface is $z = \sqrt{xy}$, the bottom surface is $z=0$. Now, the volume of the figure is given by
$$ V = \iint_D \sqrt{xy} dA$$
where $$D = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{3}\right)^4 \leq \frac{xy}{\sqrt{6}}, x\geq 0, y\geq 0\right\}$$
Now, use polar coordinates in this fashion:
$$x = \sqrt{2}r\cos(\theta), y = \sqrt{3}r\sin(\theta)$$
Then, the domain reduces to
$$0 \leq r \leq \left(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}, 0 \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}.$$
Replacing those coordinates in the integral gives
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\left(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}} 6^{\frac{3}{4}}r^2 \sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)} dr d\theta = 6^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$

This finds the volume in the first octant, but if I'm not mistaken there are three other congruent pieces of this solid in other octants. ($x$ and $y$ could both be negative; $z$ could be negative.)  Making four times this volume, if that's the intended interpretation.

That is incorrect, @2'59'2. You only work in the first octant ( the condition $x,y,z \geq 0$)

My eyes ran right past that condition.
